# Об участниках "Совещания по вопросу об упрощении русского правописания"

Tags: орфография

Пожалуйста, подскажите, кто принимал участие в "Совещании по вопросу об упрощении русского правописания" 11 мая 1917 года?

Примечание

По моим сведениям, указанное "Совещание" приняло решение "сохранить букву "ь" во всех случаях, где эта буква употребляется в современном правописании (в частности, писать "речь", "режь", "ходишь")".

Дополнение (от 14.06.2014)

В вышеупомянутом решении "Совещание по вопросу об упрощении русского правописания" величает [строчный] диакритический знак "ь" буквой.

Дополнение (от 14.06.2014)

Выяснил, что в "Совещании по вопросу об упрощении русского правописания" участвовали буддолог, индолог и сравнительный философ С.Ф. Ольденбург, историк церкви Н.К. Никольский, белорусолог Е.Ф. Карский, театраловед В.Н. Перетц.

Comment: Судя по ответу и комментариям Софии, 11 мая 1917 года в "Совещании по вопросу об упрощении русского правописания" принимало участие "общество", которое "негативно оценивало" предложение "выдающегося русского языковеда" Ф.Ф. Фортунатова, а также А.А. Шахматова, И.А. Бодуэн де Куртенэ и других "крупнейших учёных того времени" об отмене написания "мягкого знака в конце слов после шипящих".

Также можно предположить, что членами вышеупомянутого "общества" были "академики Е.Ф. Карский, Н.К. Никольский, С.Ф. Ольденбург, В.Н. Перетц", некоторые "языковеды" и некоторые "учителя школ".

Comment: Между прочим, я позитивно оцениваю предложение "выдающегося русского языковеда" Ф.Ф. Фортунатова, а также А.А. Шахматова, И.А. Бодуэн де Куртенэ и других "крупнейших учёных того времени" об отмене написания "мягкого знака в конце слов после шипящих".

Comment: Диакритики - это различные надстрочные, подстрочные, реже внутристрочные знаки.Основной альтернативой диакритикам при звукоразличении служат сочетания двух (диграфы), трёх (триграфы) и более букв для обозначения одного звука. Диакритики - это обычно точки,  хвостики, чашечки и шапочки. Вы можете привести пример из других языков, когда внутристрочный диакритик графически ничем н отличается от буквы и исторически является буквой? Или наши Ь и Ъ - это прецедент/первый случай для такого понимания диакритического знака?

Comment: Видимо, Ваши "Ь и Ъ - это прецедент/первый случай для такого понимания диакритического знака".

P.S. Я называю строчными диакритическими знаками русского языка символы "ь" и "ъ". Также, я называю "кратку" в букве "й" надстрочным диакритическим знаком русского языка.

Answer (score 2):

КАК ЭТО БЫЛО НА САМОМ ДЕЛЕ

1904-1912

В 1904 году при Отделении русского языка и словесности Академии наук была создана Орфографическая комиссия, перед которой и была поставлена задача упрощения русского письма (прежде всего – в интересах школы). Возглавил комиссию выдающийся русский языковед Ф.Ф.  Фортунатов, а в ее состав входили крупнейшие ученые того времени – А. А. Шахматов , И. А. Бодуэн де Куртенэ и другие.

Комиссия рассматривала несколько предложений, в том числе и достаточно радикальных. Вначале предлагалось отказаться от буквы Ъ вообще, а в качестве разделительного знака использовать Ь, при этом отменить написание мягкого знака на конце слов после шипящих и писать мыш, ноч, любиш. Проект нового правописания был представлен учеными в 1912 году, но утвержден не был, хотя продолжал широко обсуждаться.

1912- 1917

Вскоре после февральской революции при Академии наук была создана специальная комиссия по упорядочению правописания. Непосредственное участие в ее работе приняли академики Е.Ф. Карский, Н.К. Никольский, С.Ф. Ольденбург, В.Н. Перетц, А.А. Шахматов, А.И. Соболевский. 11 мая (24 мая по новому стилю) 1917 года состоялось совещание с участием членов Орфографической комиссии Академии наук, языковедов,  учителей школ, на котором было решено смягчить некоторые положения проекта 1912 года (так, члены комиссии согласились с  предложением А. А. Шахматова сохранить мягкий знак на конце слов после шипящих).

Июнь 2014 года

А какой вывод из этого надо сделать? Наверное, что-то похожее на речь Л. Успенского по поводу твердого знака:

«...Спасибо полезной букве, твердому знаку! Но это только сейчас он стал таким тихим, скромным и добродетельным.Недалеко ушло время, когда не только школьники, учившиеся грамоте, – весь народ наш буквально бедствовал под игом этой буквы-разбойника, буквы-бездельника и лодыря, буквы-паразита. 
Тогда о твердом знаке с гневом и негодованием писали лучшие ученые-языковеды. Тогда ему посвящали страстные защитительные речи все, кто желал народу темноты, невежества и угнетения. <...>
Уже в 1918 году буква-паразит испытала то, что испытали и ее хозяева-паразиты, бездельники и грабители всех мастей: ей была объявлена решительная война. Не думайте, что война эта была простой и легкой. Люди старого мира ухватились за ничего не означающую закорючку "ъ" как за свое знамя. <...>
...Повсюду, где еще держалась белая армия, где цеплялись за власть генералы, фабриканты, банкиры и помещики, старый "ер" выступал как их верный союзник. Он наступал с Колчаком, отступал с Юденичем, бежал с Деникиным и, наконец, уже вместе с бароном Врангелем, убыл навсегда в невозвратное прошлое. Так несколько долгих лет буква эта играла роль "разделителя" не только внутри слова, но и на гигантских пространствах нашей страны она "разделяла" жизнь и смерть, свет и тьму, прошедшее и будущее...».

Что тут скажешь? Похоже, что кто-то  и сейчас, сохраняя "ерь" после шипящих, желает  народу "темноты, невежества и угнетения".

Comment: Почему, по Вашим сведениям, 11 мая 1917 года А.А. Шахматов предложил сохранить мягкий знак на конце слов после шипящих?

P.S. Между прочим, я не называю символы "ъ" и "ь" буквами.

Comment: В Архиве АН СССР хранится рукопись доклада А.А. Шахматова, который был произнесен им на совещании 11 мая. Он предложил сохранить написание мягкого знака после шипящих, поскольку его отмена "затруднит применение нового правописания".  Предложение А.А. Шахматова оставить прежние правила о написании Ь после шипящих  было принято (в отличие от многих других пунктов) безоговорочно.  Из этого следует, что отмена Ь в рамках предлагаемой реформы было бы таким "упрощением", которое не упрощало бы, а затрудняло понимание письменного текста (соответственно, не отвечало общей задаче реформы).

Comment: Кстати, по поводу букв. Пожалуйста, приведите Ваше определение для буквы, и тогда можно будет корректно  называть/не называть буквами Ь и Ъ.

Comment: Правильно ли я Вас понял, что 11 мая 1917 года А.А. Шахматов предложил сохранить мягкий знак на конце слов после шипящих, потому что удаление мягкого знака на конце слов после шипящих "затруднит применение нового правописания" в 1917 году, в 1918 году, ..., в 2017 году, ... , в 3017 году, ..., в 4017 году, ... ?

P.S. Я не называю буквами такие орфографические символы, каждому из которых соответствует пустое множество звуков. Например, я не называю буквой  орфографический символ "/" в слове "и/или".

Comment: Думаю, что мы по-разному понимаем намерение Шахматова. Дело не в том, что в 1917 году было сложно понять удаление Ь, а со временем все бы поняли, как это правильно. Дело в том, что негативная оценка обществом этого предложения была настолько очевидна, что Шахматов опасался за принятие всей реформы. Да и в чём тут вообще проблема? Так просто понять, что наличие Ь не влияет на произношение непарных шипящих, и так просто понять, что Ь обозначает род существительных. А род существительного - это  фактически  склонение этого существительного. Запись, как у футболиста на майке: я из 3-го склонения.

Comment: И о буквах.  Буквы, по вашему мнению, не должны обозначать пустое множество. Возьмем, к примеру, слово «соль». Какая буква обозначает мягкий звук Л?  Думаю, этот звук обозначают две буквы, одна из которых Ь. Возьмем, к примеру, слово «соловьи».  А здесь какая буква обозначает звук «Й»?

Comment: В слове "соль" мягкий звук [л'] обозначает последовательность символов "ль", образованная из буквы "л" и диакритического знака "ь".

В слове "конь" мягкий звук [н'] обозначает последовательность символов "нь", образованная из буквы "н" и диакритического знака "ь".

P.S. В последовательностях символов "соловьи" и "бульон" никакая из букв не обозначает звук [й].

Comment: >Между прочим, я не называю символы "ъ" и "ь" буквами.  
 
Буква = графема. Нет никакого основания приравнивать графкму фонеме. 
Буква сама по себе можеть "кодировать" более одного звука или использоваться только в срочетании с другой

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы последовательность символов "Буква = графема." называли открытием behemothus'a.